# R: how to make system.time print the expression being timed?

Tags: r, timing

I have a big agglomeration of `R` functions calling each other, they may take a lot of time, so I call them using [`system.time`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/system.time.html):

```
f1 <- function () {
  print(system.time(f1.1()))
  print(system.time(f1.2()))
  print(system.time(f1.3()))
}
...
f <- function () {
  print(system.time(f1()))
  print(system.time(f2()))
  print(system.time(f3()))
}
```

and then the output from `f()` looks like

```
             user            system           elapsed 
129.599 (2.16min)  0.663 (663.00ms) 130.438 (2.17min) 
    wrote 447,337,021 bytes
              user             system            elapsed 
2746.37 (45.77min)  145.299 (2.42min) 2896.68 (48.28min) 
            user           system          elapsed 
 9.544 (9.54sec) 0.755 (755.00ms)  10.3 (10.30sec)
```

and it takes some time to figure out the correspondence between functions and timings.

I tried this function:

```
verbose <- function (expr) {
  ret <- system.time(expr)
  cat("<<<<<<")
  print(expr)
  print(ret)
}
> verbose(Sys.sleep(2))
<<<<<<NULL
           user          system         elapsed 
     0 (0.00ms)      0 (0.00ms) 2.002 (2.00sec)
```

Alas, it prints `NULL` instead of `Sys.sleep(2)` (i.e., the value instead of the expression).

So, how do I save the `expr`'s printed representation in `verbose` for future output?

Comment: For your function `verbose` you could use `print(substitute(expr))`

Comment: You could use package microbenchmark, e.g. `microbenchmark(f1(),times=1)`.

Comment: `system.time` is great for early profiling, but when you are looking at something complex like this, you should really move onto `Rprof` and `summaryRprof`. It will show you exactly how much time you spend in each function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function `verbose` can, by adding `substitute`, print the value that you pass to the argument `expr`.

Change the line `print(expr)` to

```
print(substitute(expr))
```

Then

```
> verbose(Sys.sleep(2))
<<<<<<Sys.sleep(2)
   user  system elapsed 
  0.023   0.007   2.009
```

Comment: flodel's comment about using `Rprof` is definitely worth note.

Answer (score 0):

While not exactly what you are asking for, I use the following wrapper to `System.time` which I keep as part of my personal utils file:

```
  s.t <- function(expr, msg="", verbose=TRUE, gcFirst=FALSE, title="") { 
  # wrapper for system.time
  # title is an alternate for msg, where user needs simply give a name to the section being timed.
  # msg is for a custome message before the sytem.time output

    ret <- capture.output(system.time(expr=expr, gcFirst=gcFirst))
    ret <- paste(ret, collapse="\n")

    if (nchar(title))
      msg <- paste0("Time to complete ", title, ":")

    if (verbose){
      if (nchar(msg) == 0)
        cat(ret)
      else 
        cat(paste(msg, collapse=""), ret, sep="\n")
    }
  }
```

---

I use this in conjunction with an optional `verbose` flag so that I can easily turn off all the timings if needed.